# Find the indices of a consecutive flag value in a 1D array

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am looking to find a value 0 in a 1D array. I have several 0 values in this array, most of the time consecutive 0 values. Now what I want exactly to do is to find the indices of the first zero value occurrence and the last zero value occurrence in each consecutive occurrences, I will give below an example to make things much clear :
Imagine I have the following array :

`A= 0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0      0.38458693526004206       0.37630968444637147       0.40920888023862656       0.37240138383511134       0.38032672100490084       0.37013107455599198       0.40263333907360693       0.36804456033540955       0.41199172743738527       0.42761170349633443       0.39300715826673704       0.39783513932402137       0.44013743441396674       0.435127008833611       0.48217350280280391       0.47501246018014148       0.49234819258730078       0.54559998531569354       0.47840534103437832       0.0                       0.0                0.0                       0.51927791704510429       0.0               0.0                        0.0                      0.0               0.0                       0.45862555500619961       0.50158980306905965       0.45676444815553296       0.49679306608627022       0.53878698007533210       0.50186256107128602       0.51714780706878094       0.53005606067091249       0.48409168179213419       0.48594430950932133       0.50963106475909081       0.49300327248076087       0.50531667704394834       0.46415085995913757       0.51930900041928330`

so I look for the first location and the last location of zero in each consecutive occurrence, I should obtain the following :

```
min_loc_1=1

max_loc_1=6

min_loc_2=26

max_loc_2=28

min_loc_3=30

max_loc_3=34
```

Now I tried a combination of `any`, `minloc`, `maxloc`, or `forall`, but I can't figure it out

```
         do ijk = 1, size(work1)
             if (work1(ijk) .eq. 0) then
                 location1(ijk) = ijk
             end if         
          end do
                    min_loc=minloc(location1)
                    max_loc1=maxloc(location1)
```

I cannot use `where`, because I am calling a subroutine inside of it, and Fortran doesn't like it apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limited amount of testing has convinced me that this solves your immediate problem. I haven't tested it extensively, I'll leave that to you. It writes the indices of the start and stop of each run of `0`s into the array `b`:

```
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: b
  LOGICAL :: zz
  ...    
  ALLOCATE(b(0))
  zz = .false.
  DO ix = 1, SIZE(a)
     IF (.NOT.zz.AND.a(ix)==0) THEN
        b = [b,ix]
        zz = .TRUE.
     END IF
     IF (zz.AND.a(ix)/=0) THEN
        b = [b,ix-1]
        zz = .FALSE.
     END IF
  END DO
```

This produces, when fed the array you show us,

```
b == [1 6 26 28 30 34]
```

If that doesn't appeal, this also seems to work:

```
  b = [(ix,ix=1,SIZE(a))]
  WHERE(a/=0.0) b = 0
  c = PACK(b,b/=0)
  b = PACK(c,(CSHIFT(c,1)-c)*(CSHIFT(c,-1)-c)/=-1)
```

If you have trouble figuring this version out stick to the explicit looping in the first snippet.

Comment: Thanks High performance Mark , both methods work perfectly, am really grateful

Comment: Be warned, further testing has shown me that neither works perfectly.  Try testing with arrays with single `0.0` in first place, and in last place.  Then figure out a fix ...

Comment: ok, I will take a deeper look, but I have tested on several arrays, and till now it seems fine to me, if it doesn't work, I will try to figure out a solution, and if I can't find one I'll ask again.